# What is the correct term for “mince pies”?

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

I have always called mince pies filled with fruit just that: *mince pies*. However, lately I have been seeing many different variations of this: *fruit mince pies*, *mince fruit tarts*, and even *mincemeat pies* — which makes absolutely no sense to me, as the pies contain no meat whatsoever.

Is there a single correct term for fruit-filled mince pies? What are the reasons for the other terms?

Comment: It would help if you provide a photo of "mince tarts".

Comment: There might be more expertise on this at [Cooking Stack Exchange](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @gmcgath I am not looking for a recipe, I am looking for the more correct term.

Comment: *Wikipedia* redirects "[mince tart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mince_tart)" to "mince pie".

Comment: I've only ever heard of mince-anything tarts or pies in kids fairy tales. Which means to me you can call them anything you like.

Comment: @Mitch Mince pies are traditional Christmas food

Comment: So the OP edits "I have always called [them] mince *tarts*" to read "I have always called [them] mince *pies*". Which is it, buddy?

Comment: @MετάEd In my opinion, mince pies and mince tarts are one and the same - only, some people had trouble recognizing what mince tarts were, so I opted for the widely recognized term.

Comment: In America, they are only, ever, and always called ***mincemeat** pies*.   Note also that *meat* does not always signify animal flesh: consider how a *nut-meat* is the kernel of a nut.

Comment: While Cookery.SE might provide a better answer, this question is on topic for here.

Comment: @bungeshea I'm assuming that people who know a subject have special expertise on its terminology as well as its practice.

Comment: I haven't heard of anyone using the words "mince" and "tart" together, until now. Is this wording only in Australian English? In the UK, there is just one term and that is "mince pies".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called mince-pies (at least the ones with a top on for Christmas)

The fruit stuff is called mincemeat, originally it contained meat with fruit and spices. Then just the suet (meat fat) with the fruit - but is still called mincemeat.

The "minced fruit" is presumably a supermarket avoiding customers getting confused about whether it's meat or fruit.

Comment: Note that in America, they are invariably called *mincemeat pies*.

Answer (score 2):

This term is a contraction of minced meat to mincemeat as the original pies contained meat minced or chopped finely and cooked with fruit, nuts and spices in pastry. The pastry would have been in pie form with a top. A tart is the same as a pie but without the top.

From OED:

> a. Meat cut up or ground into very small pieces.
>
> b. The mixture of currants, raisins, sugar, suet, apples, almonds, candied peel, spices, etc., and originally meat chopped small, typically baked in pastry, as in mince pies and other traditional Christmas dishes. Cf. minced meat n.

Mincemeat contains suet and nuts, minced fruit is just that without suet and nuts etc.

Comment: Note please that *nut-meats* are called such despite them not having any animal flesh.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, but suet is animal fat, so not entirely free of animal products. I suppose it hinges on whether fat is considered *meat* which it clearly isn't.